# Rank of Block Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $M= \begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$ be a block matrix and $A$ is square invertible.

Since
$A$ is nonsingular,
$$M= \begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\CA^{-1}&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&M/A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&A^{-1}B\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$$
My question is: why $\text{rank}(M)=\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(M/A)$, where $M/A$ is Schur - complement?

Comment: What is $A$?  And where do you get $\left[\matrix{B & C\cr C & D}\right] = \left[\matrix{I & 0\cr CA^{-1} & I}\right]$ ?  They're certainly not equal unless $B=I$, $C=0$ etc.

Comment: I edited it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two triangular matrices are invertible, so the rank is that of 
$$\tag{*}
\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&M/A\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
As this is a block-diagonal matrix, the rank is the sum of the ranks of the two diagonal entries: the rank is the dimension of the image, and the image of  $(*)$ is the direct sum of the images of $A$ and $A/M$.